# Camera Extrinsic matrix to World coordinates

Tags: c++, matrix

I have a camera Matrix, as follows:

```
 0.999995,-0.00313698,4.29446e-06, 0.632334
 0.00313675,0.999936,0.0108695,0.0111429
 -3.83917e-05,-0.0108695,0.999941,-21.8834
0,0,0,1
```

made up of the rotation matrix R:

```
 0.999995,-0.00313698,4.29446e-06,
 0.00313675,0.999936,0.0108695,
 -3.83917e-05,-0.0108695,0.999941
```

and the Translation Matrix T:

```
  0.632334, 0.0111429,-21.8834
```

What i need to do is covert this from Camera to World space. I have the formula, which is:

```
    'Rotation from camera to world is simply 
inv(R) = transpose(R). 
T is the pre-rotated camera center, 
T = -R C, so C = -inv(R) T = (x,y,z).'
```

I am a beginner at matrix math, and am confused as to how to proceed. How do i take my R matrix, and in c++, do the above?

Thank you.

Comment: google "C++ 4x4 matrix". There is plenty of free libraries and examples...

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. It is the formula i am confused about. in the:  `inv(R) = transpose(R). `, Google tells me that the inverse and a transposed Matrix are different. How can they be equal? Should I get the inverse? or the transposed matrix?

Comment: @CMouse For general matrices, inverse and transpose is something different. (E.g. Inverse is only possible on non-singular matrices, transpose is always applicable.) Matrices containing rotation only are _the_ exception - in this case inverse _is_ transpose. Thus, inverting a rotation matrix becomes a very cheap operation. See also: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_(mathematics)#Orthogonal_matrix)

Comment: ok! so, using Eigen, i can simply:  `Matrix3f R; R= R.inverse();`, is that correct?

Comment: Probably. Or, you use `R.`[transposeInPlace()](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1DenseBase.html#ac8952c19644a4ac7e41bea45c19b909c)

Comment: Got it. Thank you! If you have another minute, could you explain `C = -inv(R) T = (x,y,z).'` for me also ? is that minus inverse R * T?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135259/discussion-between-scheff-and-anti).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to nudges in the right direction from @Scheff, I have an answer:

```
void cameraMatrixToWorldSpace()
{

    Eigen::Matrix3f R0;
    Eigen::Vector3f T0;
    Eigen::Vector3f C0;

    T0 << 0.632334, 0.0111429, -21.8834;

    R0 << 0.999995, -0.00313698, 4.29446e-06,
        0.00313675, 0.999936, 0.0108695,
        -3.83917e-05, -0.0108695, 0.999941;


//inverse rotation matrix
    R0.transposeInPlace();  

    std::cout << "rotation 0: " << R0 <<  std::endl;

    //to euler radians
    Vector3f ea0 = R0.eulerAngles(0, 1, 2);

    cout << "Euler 0 :" << endl;
    cout << ea0 << endl << endl;

    //world space translation
    C0 = -R0 * T0;

    std::cout << " Translation 0 : " << C0 << std::endl;

}
```